# Dart How to implements a continuous output web-socket

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

How to realize the continuous output of data from the server to the client. For example, after receiving the `start` command from the client, the server keeps outputting the current time to the client until the server receives the `quit` command.

Questions:

1. Why can't the server receive the `quit` command
2. Why only the first client can receive the continuous output message from the server

My code in Dart is

Server:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  var running = true;
  var q = 'quit';
  var p;
  final port = 8080;
  
  var webSocketTransformer = WebSocketTransformer();
  
  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv6, port);
  server.transform(webSocketTransformer).listen((WebSocket webSocket) {
    print('WebSocket opened.');

    webSocket.listen((_) {
      q = _;
      print(_);
    }, onError: (err) {
      running = false;
      print(err);
    }, onDone: () {
      running = false;
      print('WebSocket closed.');
    });

    while (running && p != q) {
      sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
      webSocket.add(DateTime.now().toString());
    }
  });
  print('Listening..');
}
```

Client:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final url = 'ws://localhost:8080';
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url);

  channel.sink.add('start');
  channel.stream.listen((msg) {
    print(msg);
  });

  sleep(Duration(seconds: 30));
  channel.sink.add('quit');
}
```

Comment: do not use `sleep` - it blocks everything for 30 seconds - instead use `await Future.delayed` if you want to delay 'quit' command

Answer (score 1):

I think your current approach will block the socket from further clients if it's busy in an infinite loop. Your best bet is to use a Periodic Stream that will emit messages at a given interval so it can still listen for future clients.

Server:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  final port = 8080;
  
  var webSocketTransformer = WebSocketTransformer();

  // Use a periodic stream that emits events at a given interval
  Stream<int> streamPeriodic =
          Stream.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (count) {
        return count;
   });
  late StreamSubscription<int> subscription;
  bool openSocket = false;

  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv6, port);
  server.transform(webSocketTransformer).listen((WebSocket webSocket) {
       print('WebSocket opened.');
       
       webSocket.listen( (event) {
         if (!openSocket) {
              subscription = streamPeriodic.listen((event) {
                   webSocket.add(DateTime.now().toString());
              });
            openSocket = true;
         }
         else {
             event as String;
             if (event == 'start') {
                subscription.resume();
             }
             else if (event == 'quit') {
                subscription.pause();  
             }
         }
    });         
  });
  print('Listening..');
}
```